# Чтение данных... Обработка запроса... Сохранение результатов... Это ряд неполных предложений?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Часто в приложениях и на сайтах встречается следующая запись:

> Чтение данных... Обработка запроса... Сохранение результатов в базу данных...

Таким образом, последовательно называются этапы обработки данных.

Это ряд неполных предложений? Или это вовсе не предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Почему не предложения? Это номинативные, с одним главным членом.